# Not displaying properly on mobile and overlapping section

Tags: html, css, media-queries

ive been working on a website and for whatever reason i cannot hammer out the proper media queries to get it mobile responsive the css is this:

```html
.planContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 1em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.plan {
  background: white;
  width: 20em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.price h1 {
  font-size: 6rem;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 1px;
  box-shadow: inset;
  font-family: Playfair Display;
}
.price h2 {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  color: var(--charcoal);
  text-align: center;
}

.price p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Manrope;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.plan .titleContainer {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 1em;
}
.plan .titleContainer .title {
  font-size: 1.75em;
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: Manrope;
}
.plan .infoContainer {
  padding: 40px;
  color: #2d3b48;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: var(--shadow-2);
  border-radius: var(--radius-6);
}
.plan .infoContainer .priceb {
  font-size: 1.35em;
  padding: 1em 0;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-top: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80%;
  color: var(--charcoal);
}
.plan .infoContainer .priceb p {
  font-size: 2.05em;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}
.plan .infoContainer .price span {
  font-size: 2.0125em;
  display: inline-block;
}
.plan .infoContainer .desc {
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #212121;
  color: #000000;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
}
.plan .infoContainer .desc em {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.plan .infoContainer .features {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 600;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.plan .infoContainer .features li {
  padding: 0.5em;
  color: var(--charcoal);
}
.plan .infoContainer .selectPlan {
  border: 2px solid #1abc9c;
  padding: 0.75em 1em;
  border-radius: 2.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.25s;
  margin: 1em auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 70%;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.plan .infoContainer .selectPlan:hover {
  background-color: #1abc9c;
  color: white;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 10rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .price {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    height: auto;
  }

  .planContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .plan {
    flex-basis: 45%;
    margin: 1rem;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .price {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    height: auto;
  }

  .planContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .plan {
    flex-basis: 45%;
    margin: 1rem;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1080px) {
  .price {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    height: auto;
  }

  .planContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .plan {
    flex-basis: 45%;
    margin: 1rem;
  }
}
```

The Html

```html
<section aria-labelledby="price-label" class="price">
    <div id = "prices"></div>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">



    




    
    <div class="planContainer">
        <div class="plan">
            <div class="titleContainer">
              <div class="title">KVCore Setup</div>
            </div>
            <div class="infoContainer">
              <div class="priceb">
                  <p>$300.00 </p><span></span>
              </div>
              <div class="p desc"><em>Real-estate KVCore website setup, customized and modern. Stand out from the crowd!</em></div>
              <ul class="features">
                <li> Setup KVCore Site </li>
                <li> Customized Content </li>
                <li> Add Images</li>
                <li> Unique and eye catching</li>
                <li> </li>
                <li> </li>
                <li> </li>
                <li> </li>
                <li> </li>
                <li> </li>
                <li> </li>
                <li> </li>
                <li> </li>
                <li> </li>
                <li> </li>
                <li> </li>
                <li> </li>
            </ul><a class="selectPlan" href=#inquiry>Contact Us</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        <div class="plan">
            <div class="titleContainer">
              <div class="title">Basic</div>
            </div>
            <div class="infoContainer">
              <div class="priceb">
                  <p>$350.00 </p><span></span>
              </div>
              <div class="p desc"><em>Modern and basic website to showcase your business.</em></div>
              <ul class="features">
                <li> One Page Basic Website</li>
                <li> Add Menus </li>
                <li> Add Images</li>
                <li> Store Info / About Section</li>
                <li> </li>
                <li> </li>
                <li> </li>
                <li> </li>
                <li> </li>
                <li> </li>
                <li> </li>
                <li> </li>
                <li> </li>
                <li> </li>
                <li> </li>
                <li> </li>
                <li> </li>
              </ul><a class="selectPlan" href="demo1.html">View Demo</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          
        <div class="plan">
          <div class="titleContainer">
            <div class="title">Just Starting</div>
          </div>
          <div class="infoContainer">
            <div class="priceb">
              <p>$550.00 </p><span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="p desc"><em>Great for new owners wanting something simple yet elegant.</em></div>
            <ul class="features">
              <li> Elegant Home Page</li>
              <li> Add Menu's </li>
              <li> Images</li>
              <li> Social Media Links</li>
              <li> Logo Only Creation </li>
              <li> Google Ad's</li>
              <li> Search Engine Optimization</li>
              <li> Quick Inquiry And Booking Feature</li>
              <li> </li>
            </ul><a class="selectPlan">View Demo</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="plan">
          <div class="titleContainer">
            <div class="title">Getting There</div>
          </div>
          <div class="infoContainer">
            <div class="priceb">
                <p>$1250.00 </p><span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="p desc"><em>Perfect for Business's looking to streamline process's and shock new customers.</em></div>
            <ul class="features">
              <li> Luxury Web Design</li>
              <li> Shop System / Order System </li>
              <li> Animations And Animated Nav Bar</li>
              <li> EZ Book, Testimonials, Order System, And More</li>
              <li> Media / Graphic Creation </li>
              <li> Google Ad's</li>
              <li> Search Engine Optimization</li>
            </ul><a class="selectPlan" href=#inquiry>Contact Us</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="plan">
          <div class="titleContainer">
            <div class="title">Growing Needs</div>
          </div>
          <div class="infoContainer">
            <div class="priceb">
                <p>$3200.00 </p><span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="p desc"><em>The ultimate package, Useful for owners who need very specific features.</em></div>
            <ul class="features">
              <li> Animated Background</li>
              <li> Custom Feature Development </li>
              <li> Website Admin Panel</li>
              <li> Data Base Integration</li>
              <li> Intro Video </li>
              <li> Propriatary Purchase System</li>
              <li> Store Supply Quick Order</li>
              <li> Automation</li>
            </ul><a class="selectPlan" href=#inquiry>Contact Us</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </section>



<!-- 
        - #FEATURE
      -->



<section aria-labelledby="feature-label" class="section feature">
<div class="container">
<figure class="feature-banner"><img alt="feature banner" class="w-100" height="531" loading="lazy" src="./assets/images/feature-banner.png" width="800" /></figure>

<div class="feature-content">
<p class="section-subtitle" id="feautre-label"><br>Real Solutions</p>

<h2 class="h2 section-title">We make your website work for you and your business brand</h2>

<p class="section-text">Gone are the days of a messy template website made on wordpress or offered for free. Its been used a million times and shows low effort to potential customers. These websites are made from the ground up and are used to pair customers with quality businesses. Heres a taste of what you get working with me:</p>

<ul class="feature-list">
    <li>
    <div class="feature-card">
    <div class="card-icon"><ion-icon aria-hidden="true" name="checkmark"></ion-icon></div>
    <span class="span">Clean And Modern Design </span></div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div class="feature-card">
    <div class="card-icon"><ion-icon aria-hidden="true" name="checkmark"></ion-icon></div>
    <span class="span">Custom Features&#39;s To Stream Line Operations </span></div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div class="feature-card">
    <div class="card-icon"><ion-icon aria-hidden="true" name="checkmark"></ion-icon></div>
    <span class="span">Easy Booking With Google Calendar Integration </span></div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div class="feature-card">
    <div class="card-icon"><ion-icon aria-hidden="true" name="checkmark"></ion-icon></div>
    <span class="span">The only limit is your imagination </span></div>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

For times sake and incase its needed ive included the feature card section html aswell, if you would like the css for that section i can provide it though im lead to believe this stems from the plans section styling.

Below i have included images.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSAQt.png  How it should look
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnRln.png  How it looks on mobile

Any help would be great, just hate darn media queries lol

Comment: bump anyone have any advice?